# Looking for documentation setup jest for unit test of admin plugin

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, shopware6, shopware6-api

my project was created with the `swdc create-project ...`

Is there a **documentation**, a **tutorial** or **description** for the right **setup/configuration** **unit testing** with **JEST** for custom plugin in administration?

[This tutorial](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/testing/jest-admin) describes only how to write a test

But i think there must be a official setup documentation because of versions etc.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** a [**tutorial** with code is now **avialable**](https://gitlab.com/rammi2211/setup-jest-automated-testing-custom-plugins-using-shopware-docker/-/tree/master)

Using the [suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74031940/2702011) and execute the test, throws an configuration error:

```
● Test suite failed to run

Configuration error:

Could not locate module src/core/factory/module.factory mapped as:
undefined/src$1.

Please check your configuration for these entries:
{
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "/^src(.*)$/": "undefined/src$1"
  },
  "resolver": undefined
}
...
```

Cause of error:
`process.env.ADMIN_PATH` not setted but required in `%Project%/custom/plugins/%MyPlugin%/src/Resources/app/administration/node_modules/@shopware-ag/jest-preset-sw6-admin/jest-preset.js`

My solution:
set `process.env.ADMIN_PATH` in `%Project%/custom/plugins/%MyPlugin%/src/Resources/app/administration/jest.config.js`

```
// jest.config.js
...
const { join, resolve } = require('path');

process.env.ADMIN_PATH = resolve('../../../../../../../src/Administration/Resources/app/administration');
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easiest to just copy and adapt from a plugin that already has jest tests set up. Look at the [`administration` directory for `SwagPayPal`](https://github.com/shopwareLabs/SwagPayPal/tree/master/src/Resources/app/administration) for example. Copy the dependency and script sections from their `package.json`. Also copy the entire `jest.config.js`. Then within the `administration` directory of your plugin you should be able to `npm install` followed by `npm run unit` or `npm run unit-watch` and it should find `*.spec.js` files within the `test` sub-directory.